# Is width required to float two divs side by side using float:left property?

Tags: html, css

When I first learned HTML, I was told that if you want to float 2 divs side by side using `float:left`, you must set a width on those two elements. This is because a div, by default, is a block element, which will take up the full width it has available to it.

As I've built various projects, I have come across cases where floating did not work without setting a width, but then in other cases, it seems a width is not needed, and the float itself will restrict the elements width.

For example, the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/ytggLv2b/) shows two elements floating side by side only using the float property, no width was required.

```
<style>
    .left{
        background-color:yellow;
        float:left;
    }

    .right{
        background-color:green;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<div class="left">
    Floating left
</div>
<div class="right">
    Floating left
</div>
```

However, in other similar scenarios that I can't seem to reproduce right now, applying the float property to two `divs` does not allow them to float side by side unless a width is a set for both.

Am I losing my mind or is there some scenarios for which this behavior varies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... a block element, which will take up the full width it has available to
>   it.

A non-replaced block element *in normal flow* will take up the full width it has available to it. This requirement is stated at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth

A floated element is not in normal flow, so that rule does not apply. Instead, float widths are determined according to their own rules, stated and described at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width. This says that when a floated element has a computed width of "auto", its used width is determined using the shrink-to-fit algorithm.

Note that the shrink-to-fit algorithm is also used for other types of layout, including non-replaced inline-block elements and table cells, but in other respects, such as vertical alignment, the layout behaviour of those elements is quite different from that of floats.

Answer (score 3):

When set `float:left` or `float:right` on an element, it forces the creation of a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), and it behaves similarly to inline block level, the width and height are dynamic (determined by the content).